# Image of the 3 coordinate axis and the preimage of $(0,0,0)$ of a function

Tags: calculus, functions

I have the function $$f(x,y,z) = (2xy+z,3-x^2 , 1+yz^2)$$ and I have to calculate the image of the 3 coordinate axis and the preimage of $(0,0,0)$. What does it mean and how can I do that?

I guess that in order to calculate the preimage in $(0,0,0)$ I have to substitute $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ inside the preimage, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preimage of $(0,0,0)$ is the set of triples $(x,y,z)$ such that $f(x,y,z)=0$ that is

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 2 x y+z=0 \\
 3-x^2=0 \\
 y z^2+1=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.$

The second equation gives $x=\pm \sqrt{3}$. Start with $x=+\sqrt 3$ and substitute in the first equation

$2y\sqrt{3}+z=0\to z=-2y\sqrt 3$  and substitute in the third equation

$y(-2y\sqrt 3)^2+1=0 \to 12y^3+1=0\to y=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{12}}$

and $z=2\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{12}}\sqrt{3}=2\sqrt[6]{\frac{3^3}{12^2}}=\sqrt[6]{\frac{2^6\,3^3}{2^4\,3^2}}=\sqrt[6]{12}$

We get $\color{red}{\left(\sqrt{3},-\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{12}},\sqrt[6]{12}\right)}$

For $x=-\sqrt{3}$ we get

$\color{red}{\left(-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{12}},-\sqrt[6]{12}\right)}$

The image of $x$ axis is $f(x,0,0)=(0,3-x^2,1)$

$y$ axis is $f(0,y,0)=(0,3,1)$

$z$ axis gives $f(0,0,z)=(z,3,1)$

Answer (score 1):

The first coordinate axis is $a_x=\{(x,0,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb R\}$. The goal is to determine the image of $a_x$, that is, $f(a_x)$ (as well as the image of the other two coordinate axes, of course).

The preimage of $(0,0,0)$ is the set of solutions of the equation $f(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.